# The easy way to pull the first 1GiB of a text file?

Tags: linux, bash

What is the easy way to pull the first 1GiB of a text file? This can be done to produce all the 1GiB chunks of data via:

```
split -b 1G file.txt
```

But how would you pull only the first chunk and stop after that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dd`.

```
dd if=file.txt bs=1024 count=$((1024*1024))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`head(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html)

```
head -c 1G file.txt
```

The `-c` argument print the first *n* bytes. And the size *n* can be given suffixed with `G` for gigabytes.

This might be a GNU extension ([coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)). If your `head`  is non-GNU (e.g. perhaps on MacOSX), use `dd` as [answered by tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34305176/841108)

Comment: Thanks. I am checking the size of the output via "du -h out.txt" and "du -h --block-size=G out.txt" and they show "1.1G", and "2G". Do you know why